# add more logins... seems not working or pointing to wrong url

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, network-profile

When I clicked on `add more logins...` in `My Logins` page, its might be redirecting to wrong URL.

[image: My Logins page]

Wrong redirection.

[image: Not Found Redirection]

JS Development tools also not reported any error in console.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, that URL is wrong (a result of the login page redesign) - this is fixed in the next build (rev 2014.3.4.1420, meta rev 2014.3.4.2013).